# buffer.entries is not object method or class method, how to use it

Tags: node.js

In the node.js `buffer` documentation `.entries()` method is described as:

> buffer.entries() Creates iterator for [index, byte] arrays.

But this method is neither class method like this:
 `Buffer.isBuffer(obj)`  nor object  method.

So how to use this method? And example will be better.

here is code:

```
require('buffer');
var buf = new Buffer(4);
buf.entries();
Buffer.entries();
```

line 3 and 4 is error .

Comment: `buf.entries();` is ok. It will cause error if argument was not passed to: `new Buffer()` constructor.

Comment: you are right, the error is caused by the software version is too low